# how to access HTTP headers in webflux websocket WebSocketHandler?

Tags: websocket, header, http-headers, spring-webflux, spring-websocket

How can I get HTTP headers in my handler?

```
@Configuration
class WebSocketConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public HandlerMapping handlerMapping() {
        WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler = session -> {
            //httpHeaders ???
            Flux<WebSocketMessage> messages = Flux.interval(Duration.ZERO, Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                    .map("message in webSocket %d"::formatted)
                    .map(session::textMessage)
                    .take(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
            return session.send(messages);
        };
        
        Map<String, WebSocketHandler> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("/websocket", webSocketHandler);
        int order = -1;
        return new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping(map, order);
    }
}
```

I know that there is a HandshakeInterceptor in servlet stack, but couldn't find anything for the reactive stack that gives me access to HTTP headers of websocket.